# Showing modular arithmetic of primes hold as a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

> How does one show that $ \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ is a field with the operations of addition and multiplication?

I would like to show that:

$[a]+ [b] \equiv [a+b]

$a$ $mod$ $n$ + $b$ $mod$ $n$ $\equiv$ $(a+b)$ $mod$ $n$

The same for multiplication

Comment: Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: @MorganRodgers I have done so for 2. But its the modular arithmetic I'm not really use to.

Comment: @DavidWheeler just having trouble with the modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_p$ for any integer $p$. Suppose $p$ is prime. Now to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field it suffices to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain, because any finite integral domain is a field. So to obtain a contradiction let's suppose $a$ is a zero divisor in $Z_p$. Then $a\neq0$, i.e. $p\nmid a$, and choose $b\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ with $b\neq 0$, i.e. $p\nmid b$, such that $ab=0$ or rather $p\mid ab$. But since $p$ is prime $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ which is a contradiction. So $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain which is finite. Hence it is a field.

---

Or we can straightaway prove that any nonzero member of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has an inverse whenever $p$ is prime. In fact in general the invertible members of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are precisely those members that are coprime with $n$. Prove this as an exercise.

---

In your case we need to prove that $1,2$ have inverses in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. So observe that $$1._3 1=1$$ and $$2._3 2=1.$$ So every nonzero member of $\mathbb{Z_3} $ has an inverse.